# How to join two files using two columns in unix

Tags: awk, gawk

I have file a and file lookup and the structure is below.

```
vi a.txt

empid|ename|sal_grade|MANAGER_ID
1|raj|A|202
2|MAN|B|203
3|JOS|C|204

vi lookup.txt

Grade|sal|manager_id
A|$100000|202
A|$1000|099
B|$1000000|203
B|$100|011

Output:
1|raj|A|202
2|MAN|B|203

command:

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $3 in a{print $0}' lookup.txt a.txt >matched.txt
```

Here in the both files grade and manager_id is common and i want to join a.txt with lookup.txt on grade and manager_id and get the data out from a.txt where it got a match from lookup.txt .I tried with below command but it will join only on column i.e on grade column but i need to join on both grade and manager id column .

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a combined key, build a combined key.

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
  NR==FNR { a[$1 "-" $3]; next }
  ($3 "-" $4) in a { print $0 }
' lookup.txt a.txt > matched.txt
```

You can use `"-"` as a separator, or another string, or nothing at all. With the data from your example it would work without a separator.